# user_image for desire2learn LTI provider

Tags: desire2learn

I am creating an LTI tool, but do not see the user_image parameter being passed from Desire2Learn/Brightspace.

How can I retrieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brightspace does not pass this optional parameter in LTI launches. You can, however, use the Brightspace APIs to [retrieve the current, launching user's profile image](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/user.html#get--d2l-api-lp-(version)-profile-myProfile-image). (One subtle point there, though: as retrieving a user's profile image requires an (authorized) API call, you can store the API call to retrieve it as a URL, however, you'll need to wrap it with auth tokens when calling it.)

D2L's reference topic on their [Remote Plugin service](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/ui-ext/rplugins.html) contains an extended example showing how a simple tool provider can use the Brightspace APIs in conjunction with an LTI launch